# Java - Passing arguments to constructor to put into an array

Tags: java, arrays, object, constructor

So basically I'm passing 3 strings to my constructor which will then place them in already made arrays within my object/class, i'm having a bit of trouble trying to figure this out.

This is my object class

```
public class results {
String[] matchnumber = new String[9];
String[] score1 = new String[9];
String[] score2 = new String[9];
int i = 0;



public results() {


}

  public void addResults(String token, String token2, String token3) {
        matchnumber[i] = token;
        score1[i] = token2;
        score2[i] = token3;

        i++;
      }
```

This is my main class

```
>  do     { 
>             System.out.println("Enter the current Round number between 1-26");
>             roundnumber = kb.nextInt();   
>             } while (roundnumber <= 0 || roundnumber >= 27);  
>              results[] resultsarray = new results[(roundnumber)];
>     
>           for (int i = 0; i < resultsarray.length; i++) {
>               File myFiles2 = new File("Round" + (i+1) +".txt");
>               Scanner inputFiles2 = new Scanner(myFiles2);
>       
>            while (inputFiles2.hasNext()) {
>               String str2 = inputFiles2.nextLine();
>               String[] token = str2.split(",");
>               System.out.println(token[0] + " " + token[1]+ " " + token[2]);
>               resultsarray[i].addResults(token[0], token[1], token[2]); (NULL EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE)
>          }
>          }
```

As you can see Im scanning a text file to obtain 3 strings (text file contains lines of data). What i need help with is passing the 3 string tokens in my object and then saving it as an array and then processing the next batch of 3 strings into the next array index until i run out of strings in the current text file, whereby the next text file is opened and new instance of the results object is created and rinse and repeat. So yeah am i even close or completely off track lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't assign values to the arrays in the `results` constructor, since the constructor only accepts the values for a single index of the array, and your current code will only use the first (0) index of each array.

You should use a constructor that takes no arguments, and use a different method to add the data to the arrays.

Your inner loop will then look like this :

```
       resultsarray[i] = new results();
       while (inputFiles2.hasNext()) {
           String str2 = inputFiles2.nextLine();
           String[] token = str2.split(",");
           System.out.println(token[0] + " " + token[1]+ " " + token[2]);
           resultsarray[i].addResults(token[0], token[1], token[2]);
       }
```

Where `addResults` is a new method that contains the logic of your old constructor.

Comment: @cyX I don't see where you have the line `resultsarray[i] = new results();` That's what you are missing.

Comment: It compiles now, however my logic is so screwed atm. I capture the first 3 strings and assign them to the 0 index but after that i seems to be getting random values from different text files before i finish processing the current text file.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Eran.